# vb.net:Program can't save to database

Tags: ms-access, vb.net-2010

Developing a database software using vb.net but the program fails to save to database.

```
If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Application.StartupPath, 1) = "\" Then
    sConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\database2.accdb"
Else
    sConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\database2.accdb"
End If

conn = New OleDbConnection(sConnString)
conn.Open()
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PersonalData (Title, Full Name,Department,Unit,Phone No,Email,Gender,Marital Status,Birthday,Spouse Birthday,Wedding Anniversary,Educational Qualification,No of Kids,Work Experience) VALUES (@Title, @Full Name,@Department,@unit,@Phone No,@Email,@Gender,@Marital Status,@Birthday,@Spouse Birthday,@Wedding Anniversary,@Educational Qualification,@No of Kids,@Work Experience)"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Full Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@unit", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone No", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox6.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox7.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Marital Status", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox8.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Birthday", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox9.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Spouse Birthday", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox10.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Wedding Anniversary", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox11.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Educational Qualification", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox12.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@No of Kids", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox13.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Work Experience", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox14.Text
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("Data Uploaded Successfully.", , " ")
```

It shows syntax error point to `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` but the same code works on another software.

Comment: Bracket object names which contain space characters.  For example, use `[Full Name]` instead of `Full Name`

Comment: I don't think the OLEDB provider supports named parameters in this context.  In the SQL CommandText try changing the '@xxxx' to '?' for each parameter to see if that helps.

Comment: *"the same code works on another software"* - No, it doesn't. It can't.

Comment: Gord Thompson have used this same code procedure to create another database program and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You must give the error to understand what happen during the executenonquery, however looking your code if not give any error on connection MAYBE the error is inside the variables.

I do an example if you have a string where is present a special char like ' you need replace it with ''

Example:

mystring = mystring.Replace("'", "''")

Idk if can help you, without the error message it's hard help.